# data toggle inside a loop

Tags: php, jquery

I'd like to toggle a Div box (.myslide) for each record when I click on the "Ver postulantes" (DISPLAY APPLICANTS)button. if I click the first row button and the slide is displayed I want it hidden when clicking the second or third record button.

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($listaofertasres)){

    echo "<p></p>"; 
    echo "<div class='jumbotron listado'>";

    echo "<p class='list1'> Comuna : ". $row['comuna_nombre']. "</p>";  
    echo "<p class='list1'> Numero de vacantes : ". $row['vacantes_oferta']. "</p>";
    echo "<p class='list1'> Edad minima :" .$row['edad_minima_postulante_oferta']. "</p>";
    echo "<p class='list1'> Edad maxima :" .$row['edad_maxima_postulante_oferta']. "</p>";
    echo "<p class='list1'> Fecha termino: ". date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['fecha_termino_oferta'])) ."</p>\n";

    ?>
    <!--BUTTON APPLY -->
    <a href="index.php?action=ver_postulantes&id=<?php echo $row['id_oferta'];?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-default postulantes" role="button">Ver Postulantes(DISPLAY APPLICANTS) (<?php echo $row['cuenta']; ?>)</a>

      //I'd like to display it outside the jumbotron as well
      <div  class='myslide'>  </div>   

      <?php
      $cont++;
      echo "</div>";


     }
```

I tried this with no success

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $(".myslide").hide();
   $(".postulantes").on('click', function(){

            $(this).next().toggle('slow');

   });

});
```

[image]

I want it under the jumbotron and only 1 slide per button clicked

Comment: currently the box appear and dissapear immediately, i want to stay till i click another display applicant button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one makes sure you have only one slide opened at the time. It closes all slides on each click and reopens the one desired one.

Markup

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    .. content ..
    <a class="postulantes">...</a>
</div>
<div class="myslide">
  .. content ...
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // hide all slides
  $('.myslide').hide();
  // add listener
  $(".postulantes").on('click', function(){
    // if the clicked slide is not already visible
    if ($(this).parent().next().css('display') == 'none') {
      // hide all slides
      $('.myslide').hide('fast');
      // and show the slide corresponding to the link
      $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

A nicer solution would be to save a reference to the opened slide and only close this on a click.

Comment: Please explain your code for clarity, and for future readers.

Comment: great , it actually work for hidding slides after clicking on a second button, i want to display each slide outside the jumbotron

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/19juo2qj/2) or run the demo bellow ...

You should use the [slideToggle jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) instead of toggle(). Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".myslide").hide();
   $(".postulantes").on('click', function(){
      
           $(this).next().toggle('slow');

   });

});
```

```css
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;}

.myslide{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:red;
}

.postulantes{
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="postulantes">toggle</button>
<div class="myslide">a</div>
```

Comment: thanks henser, i changed it to slidetoggle but found another problem as displayed on the image